# Qt5Qmld.dll missing: could not start the simple qt application because Qt5Qmld.dll is missing

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt5

I compiled a quick Qt5 project successfully, and managed to open it with Run option in the Qt Creator.

But when I tried to run the executable file, located in the debug folder in my project,

it showed me this error:

```
The program can't start because Qt5Qmld.dll is missing from your computer. 
Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem...
```

I have searched and searched, but found nothing on google.

I found similar problems, but with different dlls, but not this one.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: `I have searched and searched, but found nothing on google.` https://www.google.com/#q=Qt5Qmld

Comment: @Paul It lead me to the same page I was in 30 minutes ago. If I found  a solution to this problem, I wouldn't ask.

Comment: And what page was that?  There are several pages that describe issues and probable solutions to this.

Comment: @Paul If you can, can you please send a link to that page you're referring to?

Comment: This is all explained in detail in the Qt deployment guide: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: @MrEricSir I don't see anything about `Qt5Qmld.dll` in that page.

Comment: @Singularity - That error, as far as I know, is a generic Windows OS error stating that a DLL can't be found.  The solution to this (as far as finding the DLL) is straightforward -- make sure that the DLL(s) that is being referred to can be accessed by the Windows OS using Window's DLL search methods (described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You need to read the entire page.  Deployment is a much, much more complex issue than a single DLL.

Comment: If you want simpler instructions with diagrams, see http://qt-project.org/wiki/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows . Also, if you want to distribute your program, create a Release build instead of a Debug build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, JKSH gave you good advice -- if you want distribute your program (pr even just use it on another computer) you need to prepare Release build instead Debug build.

As for me, the simplest method to solve your problem is to use program [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

1. Open your `exe`-file by Dependency Walker and you can see what libs you missed.
2. Goto `bin` folder of your Qt installation and find all `dll`s Dependency Walker pointed you.
3. Copy `dll`s got on (2) into directory with `exe` file of your application.

**P.S.** If you use MinGW you also need to copy next `dll`s: `libstdc++*.dll`, `libgcc_*.dll`. Copy all `dll`s as described above. Just see what Dependency Walker will say you.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I wanted. :)